# Can't select HTML5 element's children in IE8 with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html, internet-explorer-8

I found some posts with similar issues, but this is something different. I upgraded from jQuery 1.4 to 1.4.2 after I read another post, but the problem still presents itself. I also tried running IE 8 in compatibility mode and nothing seemed to work. Of course, it works perfectly well in Chrome.

Here's the markup:

```
<section class="pleaseWaitButton">
    <p><img src="images/please_wait.png" alt="Please wait" /></p>
    <p><input type="image" src="images/add_to_cart.png" alt="Add to cart"/></p>
</section>
```

Here's the only jQuery selector that *does* work in this scenario...

```
$('.pleaseWaitButton').length // 1
```

And here's the jQuery selectors that will not work!

```
$('.pleaseWaitButton').find('input').length // 0
$('.pleaseWaitButton input').length // 0
$('.pleaseWaitButton > p > input').length // 0
```

Any ideas? Anyone...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 has quirky support for HTML 5, IE6 and IE7 plain just don't support it.

**You need to [shiv](http://work.arounds.org/styling-html-5-elements-ie/) the HTML 5 elements** in order to style and properly use methods/properties such as innerHTML, getElementsByTagName on them.

This will work in IE6-IE8:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]--> 
<section class="pleaseWaitButton"> 
    <p><img src="images/please_wait.png" alt="Please wait" /></p> 
        <p><input type="image" src="images/add_to_cart.png" alt="Add to cart"/></p> 
</section> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
    alert( $('.pleaseWaitButton').find('input').length ) 
    alert( $('.pleaseWaitButton input').length ) 
    alert( $('.pleaseWaitButton > p > input').length ) 
</script> 
</html>
```

Live Demo: http://medero.org/html5.html

Comment: Note that the shiv doesn't solve all problems with the new elements; in particular `innerHTML` needs special care. I wouldn't use the HTML5 semantic container elements yet: they'll only give you IE bugs and as yet have little tangible benefit over a div.

Comment: I will say that the HTML5 elements have made my css extremely clean compared to what I've written before. For example, every time I have styles for the main item on a page, it's always my article element, so the css is super clean because I just need to style the article element. That's just one example. No need for ids in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working well so far. I don't ever ever ever use innterHTML so that's not going to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

`<section>` is an HTML5 element not supported in IE8, you'll have issues using it *as* an element, including finding children beneath it.  It isn't a jQuery problem, it's a basic DOM problem, [here's a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Gep3J/):

All I'm doing is giving the element an ID to simplify things:

```
<section class="pleaseWaitButton" id="btn">
```

Then try and get it's children:

```
document.getElementById('btn').children.length
```

This gets you a 2 in HTML5 browsers, an 0 in IE.

Comment: You can create the element manually so IE supports styling and DOM manipulating properly. There's also a fix by Jonathan Neal for printing HTML 5 elements, since IE doesn't support that for HTML 5 elements natively.

Comment: @meder - True, my answer was to *why* doesn't work, and the html5shiv code has [other issues](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/issues/list) so it's not a quick fix.  As a side note, for your example, when doing an example page, make sure to have valid HTML or it's not a valid test :)

Comment: @sfjedi - An HTML document needs a `<head>` for example :)

Comment: A `<head>` and `<title>` would have no bearing on my test case, though. Same with a `<body>` element.

Comment: Fortunately, we're all probably smart enough here to figure that part out. Thanks for the example, meder.