# Is this a bug in IE8 / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am targeting my form with a submit listener.

The HTML

```
<div id="entry-form">
   <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

The Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#entry-form form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("In Submit Form");
        });

    });
```

This works fine in all the browsers I have tested thus far. However when I try to use a `section` tag rather than a `div`:

```
<section id="entry-form">
   <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
</section>
```

The submit listener will no longer work in IE8 and instead IE8 submits the form with a page refresh. This is not the case in FF where it will work as intended.

Is this a known bug with IE8 and jQuery?

Comment: Are you using an IE shiv for the article element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352538/cant-select-html5-elements-children-in-ie8-with-jquery-selector Take a look at this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most html5 features, including "section", are not supported in IE browsers earlier than IE9.

Comment: LOL! You mean HTML 5. Funny though as one could argue it was true of IE6.