# ASP.Net MVC Ajax/InsertionMode/HTML5/IE 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, asp.net-ajax

I'm getting a weird issue in IE 8.

Here's what we got. Running Asp.net MVC 3. Using Ajax.beginform to post some databack. The response returns a view that contains HTML 5 in it (just a section tag). This works just fine in browsers that know what the heck HTML 5 is.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "main" }))
{
    <section class="stackoverflow">Hello World!</section>
}
```

However, in IE 8, when the HTML gets inserted, we get some funkiness. Inspecting the element using the developer tools show that IE 8 is self closing the section tag instead of wrapping the tag around the content like this:

```
<section class="stackoverflow"/>
Text - Hello World!
```

We are referencing the popular HTML5 shiv JS file but that doesnt seem to have any affect after page load. It appears that whatever javascript is doing the insertion, isn't recognizing the new section tag.

The other interesting thing is that when `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is false in the web.config, it works just fine. But we need to have `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` enabled for a few other reasons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` will use the Microsoft Ajax libraries whereas when its enabled, it uses the JQUery libraries. This is why there's the inconsistency between it working when disabled and working when enabled. JQuery doesnt use innerHTML when inserting the DOM elements whereas the MS libraries do.

I have found some work arounds using a plugin called [innershiv](http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/). Here are some references:
http://tomcoote.co.uk/javascript/ajax-html5-in-ie/

[Can't select HTML5 element's children in IE8 with jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352538/cant-select-html5-elements-children-in-ie8-with-jquery-selector)

We are also using HTML5 shiv which this issue is a reported bug:
http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/issues/detail?id=4